# Is there a concise way to conditionally set the variable that read will assign to?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to prompt the user and read on the same line but make the variable that's read conditional?

Something like this:

```
read -p "Enter input: " [ if some condition=true varA else varB ]
```

The manual pages for `read` don't seem to suggest that this is possible.

Comment: AFAIK not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to do this in one line.

```
if ...; then
    var=varA
else
    var=varB
fi

read -p "Enter input" "$var"
```

The argument to `read` is the *name* of a variable, so you can store that name in another variable to be expanded when you call `read`.

Alternately, just read the input into a fixed variable, *then* assign its value to the correct variable.

```
read -p "Enter input" response

if ...; then
    varA=$response
else
    varB=$response
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Just output the string...

```
read -p "Enter input: " "$(if some condition=true; then echo varA; else echo varB; fi)"
```